# Two users using the same same user profile while not in a domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, workgroup, user-accounts, roaming-profile

I have a windows server 2003 acting as a terminal server, this computer is not a member of any domain. We demo our product on the server by creating a user account. The person logs in uses the demo for a few weeks and when they are done we delete the user account.

However every time we do this it creates a new folder in `C:\Documents and Settings\`. I know with domains you can have many users point at one profile and make it read only so all changes are dumped afterwords, but is there a way to do that when the machine is not on a domain? I would really like it if I didn't have to remote in and clean up the folders every time.

EDIT-
I already have utility for scripting the cleanup, I just would rather have the extra folders not created if possible. It feels like the "correct" way of doing it.

Comment: If this needs to be moved to server fault that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a "Mandatory Profile": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307800

Apply whatever settings you want to the profile, rename the .dat to .man, then, when creating accounts in future (or modify existing), set the "Profile" field in the accounts properties to  that profile's directory.

(The link above shows how to set this path)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `delprof.exe` and set it as a system task. You can set it to a number of days that the profile is inactive and it will delete it for you.
Read more here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315411

Comment: That may be by backup choice if I can not get this to work. But What I would really like to know is can I make all users use one static single profile.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use one Demo account or a set of demo accounts. Reset the password and profile instead of creating a new one.